# Variable not available to descendant functions, events involved

Tags: javascript, variables, drop-down-menu, dom-events

I have a simple select box.  When the user chooses an option, an image and a text box containing some code should appear:

```
 <select name="state" id="state" style="margin-bottom: 1em;">
      <option value="AL">Alabama</option>
      <option value="AK">Alaska</option>
      <option value="AZ">Arizona</option>
      <!-- etc. etc. -->
 </select>
 
 <div id="badgeView"></div>
 
 <div id="codewrap" >
      <textarea id="codeView" readonly="readonly"></textarea>
 </div>
```

Here's the script:

```
/* Helpful variables */ 
var codeTemplate = '<a href="http://www.nonprofitvote.org/voting-in-yourstate.html" title="Voting in Your State">\n' + '<img src="http://nonprofitvote.org/images/badges/voting_in_yourstate.jpg" alt="Voting in Your State" />\n' + '</a>';
var state = document.getElementById('state');
var badgeView = document.getElementById('badgeView');
var codeView = document.getElementById('codeView');

/* Load up AL's image and code when the page first loads */
changeBadgeAndCode();

/* What to do when the user selects an option */
state.addEventListener('change', changeBadgeAndCode, false);

/* What to do if a user clicks in the code view text box */
codeView.addEventListener('click', selectText, false);

/* Function declarations */
function changeBadgeAndCode(){
    changeBadgeView(badgeView);
    changeCodeView(codeView);

    var stateName = state.options[state.selectedIndex].value.toLowerCase();

    function changeBadgeView(element) {
        element.innerHTML = '<img src="http://www.nonprofitvote.org/images/badges/voting_in_' + stateName + '.jpg" />';
    }

    function changeCodeView(element) {
        codeTemplate = codeTemplate.replace(/yourstate/g, stateName);
        codeTemplate = codeTemplate.replace(/Your State/g, stateName);
        element.innerHTML = codeTemplate;
    }
}
function selectText(){this.select()}
```

If I alert `stateName`, I get a value that reflects my option choice.  But that `stateName` variable doesn't seem to make it to the `changeBadgeView` and `changeCodeView` functions.  I can't understand why.  Any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're invoking `changeBadgeView` and `changeCodeView` before the `stateName` has been assigned its value.

You need to do the assignment first...

```
function changeBadgeAndCode(){
    var stateName = state.options[state.selectedIndex].value.toLowerCase();

    changeBadgeView(badgeView);
    changeCodeView(codeView);

    function changeBadgeView(element) {
        element.innerHTML = '<img src="http://www.nonprofitvote.org/images/badges/voting_in_' + stateName + '.jpg" />';
    }

    function changeCodeView(element) {
        codeTemplate = codeTemplate.replace(/yourstate/g, stateName);
        codeTemplate = codeTemplate.replace(/Your State/g, stateName);
        element.innerHTML = codeTemplate;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, @am not i am!  That makes perfect sense.

Comment: Nope, I spoke to soon.  I thought that your solution would do the trick, @am not i am, but I've run into a different problem.  changeBadgeView is executing flawlessly on change, but the changeCodeView refuses to change its original value.  It stubbornly remains set to 'al' even as the image changes to az or whatever.

Comment: @JulianJohannesen: First and foremost, you're treating the DOM as though it's a string of HTML. It isn't. You should learn to select elements and modify their properties in order to update the DOM. Second, you're overwriting the original `codeTemplate` variable, so the `yourstate` and `Your State` parts of the string no longer exist after the first time you run `changeBadgeAndCode();`.

Comment: you are awesome.  I'll work on your first point, but in the meantime, you're second point just saved my butt.  Thanks.